# Nth term formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find a nth term for this sequence?
$11.1, 15.9, 28.7, 49.5, 78.3$

I have identified first differences which are: $4.8, 12.8, 20.8, 28.8$
I have identified second difference which is: $8$

What next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation about repeated differences is spot on.

Using [Newton's series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Newton.27s_series) we get
$$
f(n)= 11.1 \binom{n}{0} + 4.8 \binom{n}{1} + 8 \binom{n}{2}
= 0.1 (40 n^2+8 n+111)
$$
if you start the sequence at $n=0$. If you start it at $n=1$, use $n-1$ in the formula.

Alternatively, a sequence whose second differences are constant is given by a quadratic polynomial and you can solve a $3\times 3$ linear system to find its coefficients using $3$ data points.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but is there any way to simplify the answer of: 0.1(40n2+8n+111)?

Comment: @KristensTaurins, it looks as simple as possible to me. What do you have in mind?

Comment: I just wondered if there is a simpler way to answer it, but thanks.

Comment: @KristensTaurins, unless you prefer $4n^2+0.8n+11.1$ or $\dfrac{40n^2+8n+11}{10}$.

Comment: It's oky now. Thanks again>>>